# Distributing your software professionally in Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, apt, debian, gnupg

I have made a .deb package which I have hosted on an Apache server. People can do apt-get install from my repository.

When people do "apt-get install mypackage". They get an unauthorized warning.

To solve the warning I signed the package with gpg and generated the public key. My client then add the public key from an url after which they don't get the warning.

Now what I want is that my client should not get warning without going into trouble of downloading public key and then adding it to apt-keys. Like any other famous software packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this for one-off packages for one-off clients, doing it the way you're doing sounds about right. They'll need to add the key, add the repo, update and then install. Bit of a long route but it can be boiled into a few commands. You could also distribute a script does the above for the user but even then you need to instruct them to chmod/run it.

If you're intending this for mass distribution (same package for lots of people) and want it to go on general sale, talk to Canonical. They have partner repos and private repos for software on sale. They'll want a cut though. You can read more about it on [the developer FAQ](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/commercial-software-faqs/) and then just [sign into the developer site to get started](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/openid/login/?next=/dev).