# How do I release software on apt-get?

Tags: apt, ppa, release-management

I'm a bit new to desktop programming, and I currently prefer to work with scripting languages (open source and all). When I polish a tool off I then want to release it for installation via apt-get but I have not found any guides or information whatsoever on how to release software on apt-get.

I understand that distributing the files to install can be done via a personal launchpad ppa, with the overhead of manually adding my ppa via `apt-add-repository` (Though I have not experienced this step, I just presume my understand is sound); Though I'm more interested in the next steps. Do I need to fill an application to get onto apt-get's default lists or what?

Appreciate your help <3

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/q/328838/158442 and also: http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/

Comment: Oh, I may be posting on the wrong stackexchange site; I'm interested in how to publish for Linux systems as a whole (though I'm only familiar with ubuntu-derived debian-like distributions). I do not want help that apply strictly to Ubuntu (laugh). I may need to delete this thread, Wish I knew more about etiquette of posting.